# Propertyinfo reflection returning Int32 not actual property names I need

Tags: c#, closedxml

I have the following code where I am trying to obtain the property names for later use. However whenever I run this it outputs the property type as Int32 with its accompanying names, I can see this in visual studio, the reflection type is correct however. If it helps the object fix I am passing in is an array. I have used this code elsewhere and it works fine without arrays so maybe that is the issue.

The reason I am passing in an object and not the exact type is I am reusing the method multiple times and overloading is not an option:

```
public void ExportResults(object fix, string fileName)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FileExport))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("File export cannot be empty", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK);
            }
            else if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FileExport))
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                using (var wbook = new XLWorkbook())
                {
                    var rec = (object[])fix;
                    int col = 1;
                    var ws = wbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
                    foreach (var propertyInfo in from propertyInfo in fix.GetType().GetProperties()
                                                 where !propertyInfo.Name.Contains("ExtensionData")
                                                 select propertyInfo)
                    {
                        int row = 1;
                        ws.Cell(row++, col).Value = propertyInfo.Name;

                        for (int i = 0; i < rec.Length; i++)
                        {
                            ws.Cell(row++, col).Value = propertyInfo.GetValue(rec[i]);
                        }

                        col++;
                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < rec.Length; i++)
                    {
                        foreach (var propertyInfo in from propertyInfo in fix.GetType().GetProperties()
                                                     where !propertyInfo.Name.Contains("ExtensionData")
                                                     select propertyInfo)
                        {
                            sb.AppendLine($"{propertyInfo.Name}: {propertyInfo.GetValue(rec[i])}");
                        }

                        sb.AppendLine();
                    }
           }
```

EDIT:

So I've resolved my issue with the following. But I have had many comments that this is not great for performance and that I should cache the properties how is this achieved?

```
public void ExportResults(object fix, string fileName)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FileExport))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("File export cannot be empty", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK);
            }
            else if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FileExport))
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                using (var wbook = new XLWorkbook())
                {
                    var rec = (object[])fix;
                    int col = 1;
                    var prop = 0;
                    var ws = wbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");

                    foreach (var propertyInfo in from propertyInfo in rec[prop].GetType().GetProperties()
                                                 where !propertyInfo.Name.Contains("ExtensionData")
                                                 select propertyInfo)
                    {
                        int row = 1;
                        ws.Cell(row++, col).Value = propertyInfo.Name;

                        for (int i = 0; i < rec.Length; i++)
                        {
                            ws.Cell(row++, col).Value = propertyInfo.GetValue(rec[i]);
                        }

                        col++;
                        prop++;
                    }
                    

                    for (int i = 0; i < rec.Length; i++)
                    {
                        foreach (var propertyInfo in from propertyInfo in rec[i].GetType().GetProperties()
                                                     where !propertyInfo.Name.Contains("ExtensionData")
                                                     select propertyInfo)
                        {
                            sb.AppendLine($"{propertyInfo.Name}: {propertyInfo.GetValue(rec[i])}");
                        }

                        sb.AppendLine();
                    }
          }
```

Comment: If you pass an `object[]` as `object` into the `ExportResults`. You get the properties of the `object[]` with `fix.GetType().GetProperties()` instead of the properties of the induvidual objects inside the array

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen is there a way around this? I am passing a specific type to `object fix` in `ExportResults` so I assumed when I do `fix.GetType().GetProperties()` it would pick that up.

Comment: You should check if the fix object is an array. `fix.GetType().IsArray` and cast it to it. and check the individual objects.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen like this? `foreach (var propertyInfo in from propertyInfo in fix.GetType().IsArray.GetType().GetProperties().ToArray()
             where !propertyInfo.Name.Contains("ExtensionData")
             select propertyInfo)` Hmm this skips over.

Comment: No, Don't get the properties of the array. Get the properties of the elements within that array. So check if it's an array... Cast it to the array.. foreach over the array and get the properties of each element

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen I'm fairly new to coding can you show an example of how I would do this? I've looked at other answers but I still get the same issue. Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do? Which library are you using? EPPlus can load a collection or DataTable into a sheet with a single call to `ws.Cells.LoadFromCollection(...)` etc. If you have to use reflection, don't retrieve the PropertyInfo objects in a loop. That's very expensive and returns the same objects every time. You can save time if you retrieve and cache the `PropertyInfo` objects. At the very least, debugging will be a lot easier if you can check the contents of a `PropertyInfo[]` array.

Comment: `rec` is `fix` cast as `object[]`. No need to check anything. If that's not throwing, `rec` already has the array of objects. Just move the PropertyInfo loop into the `for` loop, getting the properties of `rec[i]`. Caching the properties after retrieving once  would certainly be more performant if all of the objects are of the same type.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm using ClosedXML for the output no other libraries. I'm fairly new to coding so what you see may not be the best code. How do I retrieve and cache the PropertyInfo objects? Thanks

Comment: Your second loop is almost there; just replace `fix` with `rec[i]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ClosedXML already allows you to insert data into a sheet from any `IEnumerable<T>` using [InsertTable](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Inserting-Tables) or [InsertData](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Inserting-Data). `InsertTable` returns a table that [allows formatting, displaying filters and totals etc](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Using-Tables)

```
  var wb = new XLWorkbook();
  var ws = wb.Worksheets.Add("Test Sheet");

  var list = new List<Person>();
  list.Add(new Person() { Name = "John", Age = 30, House = "On Elm St."   });
  list.Add(new Person() { Name = "Mary", Age = 15, House = "On Main St."  });
  list.Add(new Person() { Name = "Luis", Age = 21, House = "On 23rd St."  });
  list.Add(new Person() { Name = "Henry", Age = 45, House = "On 5th Ave." });

  var tableWithPeople = ws.Cell(1, 1).InsertTable(list);
  tableWithPeople .Theme = XLTableTheme.TableStyleLight10;

  ws.Columns().AdjustToContents();
  wb.SaveAs("InsertingTables.xlsx");
```

A method that saves a list of items to a sheet could be as short as :

```
public void SaveExcel<T>(IEnumerable<T> items,string path,string sheet="Sheet1")
{
  var wb = new XLWorkbook();
  var ws = wb.Worksheets.Add(sheet);

  var table= ws.Cell(1, 1).InsertTable(items);
  table.Theme = XLTableTheme.TableStyleLight10;

  ws.Columns().AdjustToContents();
  wb.SaveAs(path);
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer I have just refactored and it works very well. Thank you